# Issues implementing OneSignal push notification with NextJs Pwa

Tags: next.js, push-notification, progressive-web-apps, onesignal

I've built pwa app using NextJs 13 and for the notification purpose i'm using onesignal. I'm facing these 2 issues with the notifications received by the user.

**1st Issue**
When i send a notification to a user with or without "android_group" param, the old notification gets replaced by the new notification, So to fix the issue i've currently used "web_push_topic" with all notifications being sent with unique web_push_topic. But the problem here is all the notifications act as an individual notification and are not grouped or collapsible in notification centre.

**2nd Issue**
User gets the notifications even when PWA or Web-App is opened. The behaviour i'm expecting is that it should only send notifications when the app is not running on screen.

Code for reference

```
    import * as OneSignal from 'https://esm.sh/@onesignal/node-onesignal@1.0.0-beta7';

    const configuration = OneSignal.createConfiguration({
        userKey: _OnesignalUserAuthKey_,
        appKey: _OnesignalRestApiKey_,
    });

    const onesignal = new OneSignal.DefaultApi(configuration);

    const notification = new OneSignal.Notification();
    notification.app_id = _OnesignalAppId_;
    notification.include_external_user_ids = ['user_uuid'];
    notification.web_push_topic = makeid(15); // where makeid creates a unique string
    notification.contents = {
        en: `${data.full_name} commented on your post.`,
    };

    const onesignalApiRes = await onesignal.createNotification(notification);
```